# Kubernetes Multi Path Routing Issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I’m using AWS EKS with aws load balancer controller. I have created five services and deployments and make a single ingress file. The deployment has done successfully but when i access ALB-URL with below mentioned paths in ingress file. It gives me 404 error. But the when i used EXTERNALIP:PORT/PATH it’s working fine. How can I fix the issue ?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: ee-be
  name: ee-ingress
  annotations:
    # Ingress Core Settings
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    # Health Check Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: '8012'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '15'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /rwds/*
            backend:
              serviceName: ee-rwds
              servicePort: 8012
          - path: /point/*
            backend:
              serviceName: ee-pe
              servicePort: 8013
          - path: /user-mgt/*
            backend:
              serviceName: ee-um
              servicePort: 8014
```

Comment: what is output `kubectl get  ee-ingress -n ee-be`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan
```NAME         CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS  PORTS   AGE```

```ee-ingress   <none>   *       k8s-eebacken-********.elb.amazonaws.com   80      39m```

Comment: try to access `k8s-eebacken-********.elb.amazonaws.com/rwds/*` with * is your api, using web browser.

Comment: Same: `HTTP ERROR 401`

Comment: * used as wildcard. It can be `doc` or `login` etc.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I have checked with targettype IP but still having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a ClusterIP service instead an ExternalName service.

ExternalName service example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my_service_name
  namespace: my_ingress_namespace
spec:
  externalName: my_service_name.my_service_namespace_name.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ExternalName
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```